# Either inside BlocProvider is not returning value

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I want to use `Either` to store result in `BlocBuilder`. According to result I want to show specific `Widget`. But using `Either` will throw exception that `BlocBuilder` returned `null`. I debugged that code and `fold` branch was called correctly, so it should return `Widget`. I don't understand how it could return `null`.

Code:

```
...
else if (state is Loaded) {
  final badgeOrFailure = state.profile.getBadgeByOrgId(orgId);
  badgeOrFailure.fold((err) {
       return MessageDisplay(
         message: err.message,
       );
  }, (badge) {
      return BadgeWidget(
       desc: badge.desc,
       code: badge.code,
     );
   });
...
```

Profile code:

```
Either<BadgeNotFoundFailure, Badge> getBadgeByOrgId(int orgId) {
    try {
      if (badges != null && badges.isNotEmpty) {
        return Right(badges.firstWhere((element) => element.orgId == orgId));
      } else {
        log('badges are empty');
        return Left(BadgeNotFoundFailure());
      }
    } on Exception catch (_) {
      return Left(BadgeNotFoundFailure());
    }
  }
```

Comment: please make sure that `state.profile.`  is null-safe by using `state.profile?.getBadgeByOrgId`. can you please share whole code-block related to this BLoC so that I can try to share an answer?

Comment: profile is not null. I added nullcheck but same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need an explicit `return`, for example
`return badgeOrFailure.fold(...`

Can you please try it?

Comment: This worked, but I have to keep inner returns aswell. Kinda weird that it cant return Widget from inside of fold method on its own. Because according to this syntax I logically think I want to return not Widget but Either.

Comment: that's right, inner returns must stay as well. 
p.s. i haven't done functional prog inside Dart, but similar situation happens when you use async calls and inner returns gets lost. so this led me to assume similar case for your error as well.

Comment: are you using `dartz` package for functional programming?